# DatePicker give color to unselectable date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Have a dynamic calendar in JQuery page based on data from a database the selectable dates change per user. only issue is I have one calendar when loaded from database needs to show the selectable dates only on sunday, this works fine, but I need the others days of the week to get say red every third day... this all works al long as the date is selectable, but not if not selectable?

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar .shiftColor_C a {
  color: black;
  background: red;
  border-color: blue;
  padding:3px; 
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar .shiftColor_B a {
  color: black;
  background: green;
  border-color: blue;
  padding:3px; 
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar .shiftColor_A a {
  color: black;
  background: blue;
  border-color: blue;
  padding:3px; 
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar .shiftColor_D a {
  color: white;
  background: #551111;
  border-color: blue;
  padding:3px; 
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 // Set the variable $width to the width of our wrapper on page load
     $width = $('#content').width();
     // Target all images inside the #content. This works best if you want to ignore certain images that are part of the layout design
     $('#content img').css({
          // Using jQuery CSS we write the $width variable we previously specified as a pixel value. We use max-width incase the image
          // is smaller than our viewport it won't scale it larger. Don't forget to set height to auto or else it will squish your photos.
          'max-width' : $width , 'height' : 'auto'
          });


//var array = ["8/13/2014","10/3/2014","8/25/2014"]  // date to exclude from cal, pulled from already assigned dates in DB
var array = ($("#myLeave").val());
//alert(array);
function myStartMonth() {
return '1/1/2015';
}

function noKelly(pick) {
  var kelly = ($("#myKelly").val()) - 1;
  var dow = pick.getDay();
    if(dow==kelly) return [false,''];
return [true,''];  
}

function noWeekEnds(pick) {
var dow = pick.getDay();
if (dow > 5 || dow < 1) return [false, ''];
return [true, ''];
}

function onlySunday(pick) {
var dow = pick.getDay();
if (dow > 0) return [false, ''];
return [true, ''];
}

function myAssignedLeave(pick) {
    var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('m/d/yy', pick);
    //alert(array.indexOf(string) == -1 );
    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}

function unavailable(pick) {
  var myShift = ($("#myShift").val());
  var myRound = ($("#myRound").val());
  //var myRound = ($("#LabelRound").text());

  var utcPick = new Date(pick.getUTCFullYear(), pick.getUTCMonth(), pick.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0);
  var utcStart = new Date(2014, 0, 0).getTime(); //gets utc time
  var day = Math.round((utcPick - utcStart) / 86400);

  var nkd = noKelly(pick); 
  var nwe = noWeekEnds(pick);
  var assLeave = myAssignedLeave(pick);
  var osun = onlySunday(pick);

  var Ashift = (day%3===0) && nkd[0] && assLeave[0];  // A Shift
  var Bshift = (day%3===1) && nkd[0] && assLeave[0];  // B Shift
  var Cshift = (day%3===2) && nkd[0] && assLeave[0];  // C Shift
  var Dshift = (true) && nwe[0] && assLeave[0];  // D Shift
  var Rnd1 = (true) && osun[0];  ; // First Round full weeks

  var Shift = "";
  var ShiftColor = "";
  if(myShift=="A") (Shift = Ashift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_A");; 
  if(myShift=="B") (Shift = Bshift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_B");
  if(myShift=="C") (Shift = Cshift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_C");; 
  if(myShift=="D") (Shift = Dshift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_D");; 

  if(myRound == "ROUND 1") Shift = Rnd1;

  //alert(myRound + " -- " + Rnd1 + " -- " + Bshift);

  var start = new Date(2015,0,11);
  var end = new Date(2016,0,9);
  if(pick < start || pick > end) return [false, ShiftColor, "Selection"];

  return [Shift, ShiftColor, "Selection"];   
}
```

The solution was to alter my unavailable function as follows:

```
function unavailable(pick) {
var utcPick = new Date(pick.getUTCFullYear(), pick.getUTCMonth(), pick.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0);
//-- converts your pick to utc time
var utcStart = new Date(2014, 0, 0).getTime(); //gets utc time
var day = Math.round((utcPick - utcStart) / 86400);
var nwe = noWeekEnds(pick);
var aaa = aa(pick);
var shift = (day % 3 === 0) && aaa[0] && nwe[0];

if((day % 3 === 0) && (aaa[0] === false))
    return [ false, 'green', 'Green!' ];

if((day % 3 === 0) && (nwe[0] === false))
    return [ false, 'green', 'Green!' ];

return [shift, "red2", "Unavailable"]  
}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle please ? or at least your html code.

Comment: sure http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/akgqjun2/4/

Comment: ok and you want to change the background of days other than selected ?

Comment: not selected, unselectable..., in the fiddle the 12th and the 18th are unselectable but should have the color in the 3 day pattern...

Comment: sorry for all the edits - see my last.

Comment: I dont get this point , please explain are we talking about october month ?

Comment: yes - in the fiddle, the red boxed dates are selectable the rest are not... I need the 3rd, 12th, and 18th to be red and remain un-selectable. the datepicker if set to false will not retain the cell color

Comment: here is a fiddle that does it for unselectable text not cell color: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pjJGf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

altering my unavailable function solved the problem. added a few `if` statements.

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/akgqjun2/6/

```
function unavailable(pick) {
var utcPick = new Date(pick.getUTCFullYear(), pick.getUTCMonth(), pick.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0);
//-- converts your pick to utc time
var utcStart = new Date(2014, 0, 0).getTime(); //gets utc time
var day = Math.round((utcPick - utcStart) / 86400);
var nwe = noWeekEnds(pick);
var aaa = aa(pick);
var shift = (day % 3 === 0) && aaa[0] && nwe[0];

if((day % 3 === 0) && (aaa[0] === false))
    return [ false, 'green', 'Green!' ];

if((day % 3 === 0) && (nwe[0] === false))
    return [ false, 'green', 'Green!' ];

return [shift, "red2", "Unavailable"]  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/akgqjun2/5/

```
$(".ui-state-default").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "3";
}).css("background","red")
})
```

Comment: yea thats the gist of it, I'm trying to incorporate it into the existing var shift to the dates are from there.

Comment: i dont understand , sorry but the code is kinda confusing.

Comment: how can I default this into my shift color var? since my cells are dynamically generated?

Comment: the cells that are red are determined by my shift var that gets every third day based on lenix clock - due to the date picker using "false" to set un-selectable days the css I have is determined from shift color css

Comment: in your example you used find "3" to determine cell, I use date picker time%3== 0

Comment: let me get this clear i can make a function that takes the cell you want to turn to red as argument , but these cells are specified by you right ?

Comment: look at your fiddle. `var shift = (day % 3 === 0) && aaa[0] && nwe[0];` and 

    `return [shift, "red2", "Unavailable"];` are what set the pattern of red currently in the example

Comment: need this to happen for if the `shift == false`

Comment: @BarclayVision im sorry im struggling with your code , i dont understand why is it hard for me to read it , as iam multitasking stuff right now , so cant really focus , anyway im trying to help here , i can dedicate sometime for you but please promise to respond quickly.

Comment: i think I see where I'm confusing things... I'm getting my pattern from the var SHIFT, `(day%3===0)` but I'm also excluding weekends and another array of dates from another source - I just need the red color to be all dates from the SHIFT var.